# Dump a MX25L12845E with a bus pirate and flashrom

Tags: dumping, spi, flash

I just received my buspirate, I now want to dump a flash ([MX25L12845E](http://www.macronix.com/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/2497/MX25L12845E,%203V,%20128Mb,%20v1.9.pdf)).
I tried the following command:

```
flashrom -V -p buspirate_spi:dev=/dev/tty.usbserial-AJ02XILF,spispeed=1M -r MX25L128.bin -c MX25L12835F/MX25L12845E/MX25L12865E
```

And get the following output:

```
flashrom v0.9.8-r1888 on Darwin 15.0.0 (x86_64)
flashrom is free software, get the source code at http://www.flashrom.org

flashrom was built with LLVM Clang 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72), little endian
Command line (7 args): flashrom -V -p buspirate_spi:dev=/dev/tty.usbserial-AJ02XILF,spispeed=1M -r MX25L128.bin -c MX25L12835F/MX25L12845E/MX25L12865E
Calibrating delay loop... OS timer resolution is 1 usecs, 2849M loops per second, 10 myus = 10 us, 100 myus = 149 us, 1000 myus = 1019 us, 10000 myus = 9791 us, 4 myus = 14 us, OK.
Initializing buspirate_spi programmer
serialport_config: Some requested options did not stick.
Error: Programmer initialization failed.
```

I check the Internet but it look like nobody already had this problem.

I tried to look at the pinout once again, still nothing.

Then I change some connection to see if I can have a different error, but no.

Did someone already had this problem?

EDIT: This error message come from this part of code:

```
wanted.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | CSTOPB | CSIZE | CRTSCTS);
wanted.c_cflag |= (CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD);
wanted.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
wanted.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY | ICRNL | IGNCR | INLCR);
wanted.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &wanted) != 0) {
    msg_perr_strerror("Could not change serial port configuration: ");
    return 1;
}
if (tcgetattr(fd, &observed) != 0) {
    msg_perr_strerror("Could not fetch new serial port configuration: ");
    return 1;
}
if (observed.c_cflag != wanted.c_cflag ||
    observed.c_lflag != wanted.c_lflag ||
    observed.c_iflag != wanted.c_iflag ||
    observed.c_oflag != wanted.c_oflag ||
    cfgetispeed(&observed) != cfgetispeed(&wanted)) {
    msg_perr("%s: Some requested options did not stick.\n", __func__);
    return 1;
}
```

The `PARENB | CSTOPB | CSIZE | CRTSCTS` and so on part look like it's a problem due to terminal.

BTW I use `iTerm` and `Terminal` and it's not working on both. But works on Linux with default terminal.